# Questions about non-standard test statistic for difference of two population proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, proportion, exact-test

#### Background

I'm considering the number of observed 'successes' $x_1$ and $x_2$ from $n_1$ and $n_2$ independent trials respectively. These counts can be considered realisations of random variables $X_1, X_2$  such that $X_1 \sim Bi(n_1, \pi_1), X_2 \sim Bi(n_2, \pi_2)$ and $\pi_1,\pi_2$ are the proportion of “successes” in the true population.

I would like to determine the probability of observing equal or more extreme than $x_1,x_2$ given that in the true population $\pi_2 \ge \pi_1$". The null and alternative hypothesis are therefore 
$$H_0:  \pi_2 - \pi_1 \ge  0$$
$$H_1:  \pi_2 - \pi_1 \lt 0$$

and I want the probability of observing counts which are equal or more extreme than those observed given the null hypothesis is true, i.e.
$$
P(X_1 \ge x_1 \wedge X_2 \le x_2 | \pi_2 - \pi_1 \ge  0)
$$

One way to solve this probability without knowing the nuisance parameter $\pi_{i}$ is  using the supremum approach suggested by Barnard (1945).  Given some test statistic, $T(X_1,X_2)$, the probability of observing $(x_1,x_2)$ under the null as
$$
P =  \max_{0 \le \pi_1\le \pi_2 \le 1}\sum\limits_{T(X_1,X_2) \ge T(x_1,x_2)} P(X_1,X_2|\pi_1,\pi_2)
$$
where $T(X_1,X_2)>T(x_1,x_2)$ is $X_1 \ge x_1 \wedge X_2 \le x_2 $. In this case, $P(X_1,X_2|\pi_1,\pi_2)$ is just a product of binomials.

#### Question

I'm concerned that the "test statistic" suggested above does not really fit into the scheme of $T(X_1,X_2)>T(x_1,x_2)$ as the conjunction of inequalities can't be separated into individual scores. Instead, I'm sort of doing two tests on each table and combining them.  Concerningly, Q-Q plot for counts generated from random trials (below) shows that the resulting probabilities from this test are non-uniform and overly liberal, whereas using a Wald test as the test statistic appears to follow the expected uniform distribution reasonably well. 
[image]

I'm therefore concerned that by abusing my choice of test statistic, I'm not generating "correct" (uniform) p-value but I'm not sure.

Is my use of $X_1 \ge x_1 \wedge X_2 \le x_2 $ as a test statistic reasonable?

If it is, I'd be keen to hear why the use of this test leads to apparently liberal $p$-values and whether its similar to anything in the literature.

And if its not reasonable, I'd be keen to hear why and what a suitable alternative would be
that still.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to clearly specify what you want to test? What is your null hypothesis and what is your alternative hypothesis?

Comment: @Peter: I've tried to phrase hypotheses clearly and made the whole thing more succinct. Please let me know if the question remains unclear. I find it a struggle to phrase these types of problems easily :)

Comment: You need to look into theory of comparing 2 proportions. See page 4-7 of [this document](http://www.ncss.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Tests_for_Two_Proportions.pdf).